# Official Rollup GraphQL plugin not working in a Sveltekit project?

Tags: graphql, vite, sveltekit, rollup

I have a sveltekit project which leverages the [official rollup graphql plugin](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/graphql#rollupplugin-graphql) to import schemas from files ending in `.graphql` or `.gql` as pre-processed typed ASTs.

I followed the [vite compatability and usage guide](https://vite-rollup-plugins.patak.dev/#graphql) and cannot seem to get the plugin to work.

*The typescript compiler throws the error:*

```
Cannot find module '$lib/schema.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

*While I also have the following runtime error:*

```
ReferenceError: SayHello is not defined
```

So the plugin is essentially not working, as the graphql import is not being recognized as a module. Here is my code:

```js
// vite.config.ts

import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import graphql from "@rollup/plugin-graphql"

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [graphql(), sveltekit()]
});
```

```
# src/lib/schema.graphql

query SayHello {
    hello
}
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/+page.svelte -->

<script lang="ts">
    import { SayHello } from '$lib/schema.graphql'; // Cannot find module '$lib/schema.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations.
</script>
```

The **$lib** alias shouldn't be the issue, I also tried relative paths.

Comment: The plugin randomly began working and I am now able to import pre-processed ASTs directly from graphql files, however there is no typesafety as typescript still does not recognize the graphql imports.